# Builder C++ DBExpress clientdataset : insufficient memory for this operation

Tags: c++builder, vcl, dbexpress, tclientdataset

i have a problem when i try to fill my DBGrid from datasource:

my code

```
void MyClass::initializeGridView()
{
    String sqlFilter = SrcQryStringList->Text + QueryStringList->Text;

    FilterSQLQuery->Close();
    FilterSQLQuery->SQL->Clear();
    FilterSQLQuery->SQL->Add(sqlFilter);
    FilterSQLQuery->Active = true;

    DocumentsDataSetProvider = new TDataSetProvider(this) ;
    DocumentsDataSetProvider->DataSet = FilterSQLQuery;
    DocumentsDataSetProvider->Name ="DocumentsDataSetProvider";

    DocumentsClientDataSet = new TClientDataSet(this);
    DocumentsClientDataSet->ProviderName = DocumentsDataSetProvider->Name ;
    DocumentsClientDataSet->Active = true; // "insufficient memory for this operation"


    DocumentsDataSource= new TDataSource (this);
    DocumentsDataSource->DataSet = DocumentsClientDataSet;

    JvDBGrid1->DataSource =  DocumentsDataSource;

    delete DocumentsDataSetProvider;
}
```

FilterSQLQuery is a TSQLQuery, JvDBGrid1 is a DBgrid

I get this error "insufficient memory for this operation" with high count of returned row!

Thx

Comment: How many is a "high count" of returned rows? Is this a 32 or a 64 bits program? In MB, how much space do the resulting dataset need? I would expect that you will need that many MB free in your client app and then some to be able to load them all in the ClientDataSet.

Comment: high count~33000..
32 bit program..
i don't how much space the resulting dataset need

Comment: But a quick calculation? 33k records shouldn't be a problem, unless each record is quite big. And your code mentions "Documents", do you have big BLOBs or something like that?

If you get, say, just half of the records, does it work? If you check the memory usage of your app with Task Manager or Process Explorer, how much memory gets consumed? It's not the best way to profile memory usage, but for something quick it could probably give you an idea

Comment: each row contain more than 100 columns.. i haven't a big Blob..

Comment: i have CountColumn in my query ~250.. No big Blob in my all colummns.. at same time, i get this error "insufficient memory for this operation" caused by my ClientDataSet.. can i use other way to fill my DbGrid with my query Select * from FiltreView where DocID>xxx ??